K6 sends 4 times more requests than it should
Kindly asking for your advice. I noticed that my k6 script with Ramping arrival rate sends much more requests than it should. I set following stages:
import http from 'k6/http';

export const options = {
    scenarios: {
        contacts: {
            executor: "ramping-arrival-rate",
            startRate: 0,
            timeUnit: "1s",
            preAllocatedVUs: 1,
            maxVUs: 50,

            stages: [
                { target: 10, duration: '30s' },  // Ramp Up
                { target: 10, duration: '3m' },   // Keeping load level
                { target: 1, duration: '30s' },   // Ramp Down
            ],
        },
    },
};

export default function () {
    const res = http.get(`https://mywebsite.com`);
}

I expected to receive 10 rps load with these settings, but in fact I got 40 rps.
Grafana metrics screenshot |
k6 report screenshot
So I tried to use another arrival instead and created easy test plan with Constant arrival rate
import http from 'k6/http';

export const options = {
    scenarios: {
        contacts: {
            executor: 'constant-arrival-rate',
            rate: 10,
            timeUnit: '1s',
            duration: '1m',
            preAllocatedVUs: 5,
            maxVUs: 50,
        },
    },
};

export default function () {
    const res = http.get(`https://mywebsite.com`);
}

I ran K6 with this script and received the same picture again: 10 iterations per second, but 40 requests per second.
Grafana metrics screenshot |
k6 report screenshot
I also tried to add sleep to default function but it didn't help.
Why does this happen? How can I make k6 make load level exactly 10 rps?
It would be perfect if k6 would load my website with needed rps and if stages would work too.

That should work. Are you executing the correct test file? Which k6 version? Can you try a different/older/newer version of k6?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. (k6 reports are text)

Found the reason of this issue.
This script cauches redirects and each redirect is counted as a new rps.
So my test has 10 iterations per second and at the same time 40 requests per second.
Ways to solve it:

Add maxRedirects: 0
Count iterations in grafana dashboard instead http requests.


But that means your script is in fact making 40 requests per second. If you disable redirects, you would be no longer hitting your web service, would you?

In fact it realy does. The problem is with count logic only.
The script does 1 request and then just folows redirects.
In the same situation JMeter counts request with all its redirects as 1 request.
So when I try to replicate JMeter rps counting logic using k6 - I just need to choose "FROM iterations", not "FROM http_reqs" when creating a grafana panel.
